# With the Science.bst template file, references for journal articles are not properly displayed

Tags: latex, bibliography

I'm using the Science .bst file from https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/Science.bst

And the references that are generated do not comply with the Science reference style, see https://www.sciencemag.org/authors/instructions-preparing-initial-manuscript

Specifically, only the first page from the "pages" field is shown, and the article title is not displayed.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
@article{blumenstock2016fighting,
  title={Fighting Poverty with Data},
  author={Blumenstock, Joshua Evan},
  journal={Science},
  volume={353},
  number={6301},
  pages={753-754},
  year={2016},
  publisher={American Association for the Advancement of Science},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{blumenstock2016fighting}

\bibliography{reference}
\bibliographystyle{Science}

\end{document}
```

gives

[1] J. E. Blumenstock, *Science* **353**, 753 (2016).

Answer (score 8):

The following patch to Science.bst resolves this issue.

https://gist.github.com/luna983/d53f9c4ca52b52661bc863498966a8ca/revisions

- On line 812: delete `first.page`
- After line 1038: add a line `format.title "title" output.check`

The output from the MWE is now

[1] J. E. Blumenstock, Fighting poverty with data, *Science* **353**, 753-754 (2016).

Comment: As the file is licensed under the LaTeX Project Public License, please don't redistribute the modified file under the same name. Please give it a different name, e.g. `Science_Luna.bst`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to piggyback on the answer to the previous question, which was answered by [Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6657998/luna) in her [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68503925/9685500).

There is another inconsistency between the Science bibstyle and the reference style guide. Namely, the author list should *not* be shortened (i.e. no 'et al.'). From the [style guide](https://www.science.org/content/page/instructions-preparing-initial-manuscript):

> Journal article references should be complete, including the full list of authors, the full titles, and the inclusive pagination.

A hot fix to achieve this is in Science.bst:

- On line 503: change `numnames #5` to a number higher than the longest author list count, e.g. `numnames #100`